# How to draw a map using python

Tags: python, dictionary, contour

I want to draw a map using python, not really a map with full information, just a get together of a series of small shapes to reflect land use.

The data is like below

```
1 2 2 3 3 2
2 3 3 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 3 3
3 3 3 3 4 1
```

Each number represents one land use type. and their positions in the matrix are their coordinates.

I used VBA to do that before, the whole map consists many small square shapes representing land use, but since the data was so large, it took a long time to generate the map, also delete the map.

My question are :

1. I wonder in python, is there any more fast way to generate this kind of map, as a whole, not a series of shapes, i think that would be faster？？
2. I have tried using contourf, as below, but it says "out of bounds for axis 1", but actually, I printed X,Y and cordi, they have the same shape, why still out of bounds?

   ```
   y = np.arange(0, 4 , 1)
   x = np.arange(0, 6 , 1)
   X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

   # cordi is the matrix containing all the data
   # pyplot is imported before

   plt.contourf(X,Y, Cordi[X,Y], 8, alpha=.75, cmap='jet')
   ```

Thank you very much for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), which produces something like a heatmap. Here is an example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [3]: coord_data = np.array([[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2], 
                               [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1]])
In [4]: map = plt.imshow(coord_data)
In [5]: plt.colorbar(map)
Out[5]: <matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar instance at 0x7f3df2559c20>
In [6]: plt.show()
```

[image]

You can specify the interpolation level using the `interpolation` keyword ([examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_interp.html)), and the colors used using the `cmap` keyword ([example colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)).

If you don't use `interpolation='nearest'`, neighboring data points with the same value will look like contours.

Comment: im sorry, but i just found this is probably not what i want, according to its explanation on the website, imshow deals with images not plots. and if I only got a 2D array, so for each pixel, i only have one value, where 3 values of colors are needed for each pix.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  The colormap takes a single value and maps it to a color.  So for example, say you have values that range between 1 and 10.  The colormap might take values near 1 and map those to blue: `(0,0,255)`, values near 10 to red: `(255,0,0)`, and values inbetween to green `(0, 255, 0)`. What I have plotted above uses only a 2D array of single values.

Comment: Ah, so you mean, if I didn't assign RGB(for example red(255,0,0)), the colors will automatically change with the values(for example 1 to 10), then I know why it doesn't work, because in the txt file, the valid value is from 1 to 5, the invalid value is always -9999, so no wonder it couldn't distinguish the valid value. thanks. @wflynny

Comment: @rankthefirst If you have "invalid" datapoints, you can use the `vmin` keyword to specify that values below `vmin` shouldn't be plotted. For example, if you real data spans `[1,5]`, but you have invalid data points set to `-9999`, then you can do `imshow(coord_data, vmin=1)`, and the invalid data points will show up as white (if using the default colormap - `jet`).